# How to add Syntax highlighting for .Vue files in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, vue.js

I just want to ask if you know how to add syntax highlighting for vue files using vue-loader. I'm using Eclipse Neon

Comment: Vue-loader does not do the syntax highlighting. Its the IDE you use which does the syntax highlighting. Search if eclipse has an vue plugins for syntax highlighting of vue related code. Otherwise i suggest using webstorm(paid) or atom(free) as a IDE

Answer (score 13):

vue is mostly tags and javascript so treating it as a HTML file would be fair enough. That can be set in eclipse for *.vue under HTML in content type.
[image]

Answer (score 4):

There is a plugin in the Marketplace that might be what you're looking for. It's called CodeMix CI 1. I just installed it and aside from adding syntax highlighting, it also does code completion, which comes really handy.

Comment: Take a look at [this page](https://www.genuitec.com/tech/vue-in-eclipse/) to see some of the Vue capabilities in CodeMix:

Comment: Good stuff, @BrianFernandes. Very informative link, thanks!

Comment: It should at least be noted that CodeMix is not a free plugin for eclipse.